# Month pagination with kaminari

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, pagination, mongoid, kaminari

I want to paginate posts by month so I added following scope in Post model

```
class Post
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  scope :by_month, lambda {|end_date| Post.order_by(:created_at => :asc).where(:created_at.gte => (end_date.to_date.beginning_of_month), :created_at.lte => (end_date.to_date))}
end
```

In my controller I put

```
def show
  @posts = Post.by_month(Time.now).page(params[:page]).per(20)
end
```

In view

```
<%= paginate @posts, :theme => 'month_theme' %>
<%= render @posts %>
```

Problems:

1. pagination is not working by month, I want to show all result of a month in a page, replacing params[:page] by params[:month]=2 or params[:month]=Feb
2. How do I view 'August 2011' instead of 1,2
3. Loop month and year like when you goto previous while in 'Jan 2011' it will goto 'Dec 2010'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suppose this is not really a matter of pagination. Dealing with the params[:month] value for the query is something different from the page offset switching. You might not need a pagination library for that.

How about simply creating those links like this?

controller:

```
@posts = Post.by_month(Time.parse(params[:month]) || Time.now)
```

view:

```
<% Post.only(:created_at).map {|p| p.created_at.to_date.beginning_of_month}.uniq.sort.each do |m| -%>
  <%= link_to_unless_current m, :month => m %>&nbsp;
<% end -%>
```

Of course you can combine this query with normal pagination if needed. But the pagination links should not be mixed with the month links in that case.